# how is the running time for constant-sized input constant?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, asymptotic-complexity

I came across this statement in Cormen:

> Since the running time of an algorithm on a constant-sized input is a constant, the recurrences that arise from the running times of algorithms generally have
>   T(n)=theta(1) for sufficiently small n.

But if we consider sorting then even if the input size is constant the running time changes(when the input is already sorted contrasted with the case the input is in the descending order and we have to sort it into the ascending order).How can the running time be constant?

Comment: If n is really small, like n = 10 or n = 2 than algorithms work really fast. And if another variables in algorithm is much bigger than n than it is possible to suppose that time is constant

Comment: The upper and lower bounds for the best, worst and average cases are constant for constant-sized input. "The running time [complexity] ... is constant" should not be taken to mean "it always takes exactly the same amount of operations for any input of that size".

Answer (score 0):

Let's say we compare 3  Algorithms

- **A** with running time of exactly: 122n+1 (= **O(n)**)
- **B** with running time of exactly: 5*n²+4*n +17 (= **O(n²)**)
- **C** with running time of exactly: n³ +20 (= **O(n³)**)

If we git each the same input of constant size n=4 we get different running times

- A: 144 time units
- B: 113 time units
- C:  84 time units

Even if the all the three algorithms have different complexity the results for a specific (constant) value of n produce a constant running time.

So from the result 144 113 84 you can say nothing about the complexity of the different algorithms for other values of n.

So the O-Notation only makes sense if you want to describe the behavior of an algorithm for all possible variables of n. If you are only interested in the running time of a specific n the O-notation is of no use because it tells you nothing about factors. In my example above the algorithm with the worst complexity (C) had the lowest running time for the given n=4.

In short: No matter what the complexity of an algorithm is, if you put in a problem of a constant size you will always get a constant running-time.

The o-notation only describes the running time changes in relation to different input sizes and also abstracts from any constant factors.

[wikipedia Big O-notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)

Comment: I think an example of OP was talking about is something like linear search for n=1000, which can take anywhere between 1 and 1000 comparisons, depending on where the element we're looking for is. This answer doesn't appear to address that.

Comment: @Dukeling: Even for n=1000 it is only a constant amount of comparisons no matter if the Algorithm is O(n) or O(n²) or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Using an established algorithm for the given problem precompute a table that contains in column 1 all the different inputs of size `n` and in column 2 the output of the algorithm corresponding for the input in column 1 of the same row. Now the modified algorithm is to use the input as an index to the table column 1 and just output what is contained in column 2 in that row.

The table's size is some fixed `m` as it is precomputed. So the runtime of the modified algorithm is only dependent on `m` as it needs to output some data at most the size `m`. Therefore the runtime of the modified algorithm is `O(1)`.